# Page layout is broken when viewing search results.

Tags: css

This is my careers first WordPress theme: [Click Here](http://codepen.trafficopedia.com/site01/).

If you search anything than the design breaks. Search for example this string → The Authors Name

I could not understand why only search results breaks the design, and I remember 2 weeks back I think all this was working fine?

Please let me Know if you need code. i think the code is not required so initially I am not posting the code.

This is the code in `searchform.php`:

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
    <label>
        <span class="screen-reader-text"><?php echo _x( '', 'label','simplisto' ) ?></span>
        <input type="search" class="search-field"
            placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search', 'placeholder','simplisto' ) ?>"
            value="<?php echo get_search_query() ?>" name="s"
            title="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search for:', 'label','simplisto' ) ?>" />
    </label>
    <input type="submit" class="search-submit"
        value="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search', 'submit button','simplisto' ) ?>" />
</form>
```

Please let me know if some other code is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the markup. On the search results page, the `<body>` element is assigned the classes `search` and `search-no-results`.

```
<body class="search search-no-results">
```

Looking at the CSS, the styles for `.search` are intended to be used for the search input. They are working for that, but they are also being applied to the body due to the use of a weak selector:

```
.search {
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    padding: 5px 7px;
    /*margin-left: 15px;*/
    width: 175px;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;
    /*position: absolute;*/
    right: 0;
    /*float: right;*/
}
```

That's no good. I'd update the selector to be more specific:

```
input.search {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, sir. Can I request you to please elaborate a little bit more? where was I wrong? bad coding practice? bad CSS was written or something else. please guide me, sir, as this will help me to graduate one step further.

Comment: I'd say the takeaway here is that when a layout issue arises unexpectedly, fire up the dev tools and verify that the HTML is correct. While you're there, inspect the CSS that's being applied. Keep in mind that the body_class() function adds different classes based on what page is being viewed.

Answer (score 0):

If you search anything and design breaks so you have to check your file
" template-parts/content-search.php " if there where any desing or code error is left 
And as alternate you can add css in in style.css

.search-form {
    position: relative;
}